# Discord.js maximum number of webhooks error

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Have this slash command code and turned it into webhook. It worked when I used it once but it stopped working after that. I got this error `DiscordAPIError: Maximum number of webhooks reached (10)`. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Code:

```js
    run: async (client, interaction, args) => {

      if(!interaction.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) {
        return interaction.followUp({content: 'You don\'t have the required permission!', ephemeral: true})
      }
      
        const [subcommand] = args;

  const embedevent = new MessageEmbed()

        if(subcommand === 'create'){
        
            const eventname = args[1]

            const prize = args[2]

            const sponsor = args[3]
            
            embedevent.setDescription(`__**Event**__ <a:w_right_arrow:945334672987127869> ${eventname}\n__**Prize**__ <a:w_right_arrow:945334672987127869> ${prize}\n__**Donor**__ <a:w_right_arrow:945334672987127869> ${sponsor}`)
            embedevent.setFooter(`${interaction.guild.name}`, `${interaction.guild.iconURL({ format: 'png', dynamic: true })}`)
            embedevent.setTimestamp()

        }
        
        await interaction.followUp({content: `Event started!`}).then(msg => {
    setTimeout(() => {
  msg.delete()
}, 5000)    
  })    

        interaction.channel.createWebhook(interaction.user.username, {
     avatar: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})
 }).then(webhook => {    
webhook.send({content: `<@&821578337075200000>`, embeds: [embedevent]})
  })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fix that error, discord limits webhooks per channel (10 webhooks per channel).

However, if you don't want your code to return an error you can just chock that code into a `try catch` or add a `.catch`

Here is an example of how to handle the error:

```js
try {
    interaction.channel.createWebhook(interaction.user.username, {
        avatar: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})
    }).then(webhook => {    
        webhook.send({content: `<@&821578337075200000>`, embeds: [embedevent]})
    })
} catch(e) {
    return // do here something if there is an error
}
```

Comment: Does that mean, I won't be able to use its command after 10 webhooks? Or is like a cooldown for example, 10 webhooks per channel in a certain length of time?

Comment: @Heko you wont be able to use the command after 10 webhooks